# Why is server response to Ajax request always considered as success?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, extjs, server

I have an Ajax request in EXTJS like:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: url,
    scope: me,

    success: function(response, opts){
        console.log('OK');
    }, 
    failure: function(response, opts){
        console.log('Error');
    },   
});
```

And from server side I return either:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
$result['success'] = true; 
$result['msg'] = 'User authenticated!';
echo json_encode($result);
```

or:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 555 Invalid email or password.");
$result['success'] = false; 
$result['msg'] = 'Invalid email or password.'; 
echo json_encode($result);
```

This works well on localhost, but I have noticed that when this code runs on server both responses are treated as `success`.
So, in both cases I am getting 'OK' as console log. I thought that response is classified as success or failure depending on the header (200 is success and anything else is failure). But, obviously, this is not how it works. I am wondering why this happens, especially beacuse on localhost it works as expected.

**Update**

When I set response code to be 555 in second case with

```
        header("HTTP/1.1 555 Invalid email or password.");
        var_dump(http_response_code(555));     //   <-  here I set response code
        $result['success'] = false; 
        $result['msg'] = 'Invalid email or password.'; 
        echo json_encode($result);
```

I got response in network tab

```
int(555) {success: false, msg: "Invalid email or password."}
msg: "Invalid email or password."
success: false
```

However If I only use `var_dump(http_response_code(555));` without header:

```
        var_dump(http_response_code(555));
        $result['success'] = false; 
        $result['msg'] = 'Invalid email or password.'; 
        echo json_encode($result);
```

I got response in network tab:

```
int(200) {success: false, msg: "Invalid email or password."}
msg: "Invalid email or password."
success: false
```

So, on local computer I get

[image]

but, when application is hosted on a server regardless of the output I always get

[image]

Comment: You can set the response code using [http_response_code()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php). Check and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked, and it doesn't change anything. When I run code on localhost on my computer (xampp), everything is ok, but when application is hosted on server I always get  success regardless of response.

Comment: Have you checked the network tab in your browsers development tools to see what the response from PHP actually looks like?

Comment: It seems that the problem is due to asynchronous call.  But, it is still confusing why this behaves differently when application sits on local computer or on remote server.

Comment: That wouldn't make any difference. Did you do as Magnus suggested? It isn't clear from your response what you actually checked or what led you to the conclusion you've just stated.

Comment: Yes, I did as Magnus suggested. Please take a look at the updated question.

Comment: You've only posted the output of the body (your var_dump() and echo). In the network tab, you can see what response code the actual request gets. Under "Network", you should see the URL that's being called and next to it, you should have a column called "Status". What does it say there?

Comment: I am always getting Status Code: 200 regardless of the output.

Comment: If you always get 200 on the server but it works locally, then it sounds like there's something on the server, other than your code, that changes it. What do you get if you break the script? Like removing a semi colon from one of the lines? Do you get status code 200 or 500?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that is very strange.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean to remove semi colon.

Comment: If you meant to intentionaly make syntax error, I tried and I get 500

Comment: Ok, that's good. Now put it back. And what if you try to use status 400 Bad Request in your code?  That would be a more semantically appropriate code to use for your situation anyway. 555 is a) still a draft status, not yet standardised to my knowledge, so you can't assume support for it, and b) meant to indicate a server side error, whereas what you're indicating is that the user supplied incorrect data. In fact if this is a login script, you might even want to return 403 Forbidden actually.

Comment: Yes, I tried with '400 Invalid email or password.', and it works as expected (it is also interesting that it doesn't have to be 400 Bad Request). I thought that anything except 200 is considered failure. It also works with 503 or 506, but for some reason 551 returns success. So, it''s better always to stick to 400 just in case.

Comment: It's good that 400 works. Not 100% sure why this happening I would guess that 555 or 551 are maybe not recognised yet by the webserver that your code is passing through before it returns back to the client, and it's resetting the status code before it returns the response. Possibly it assumes you have made a mistake. But that's just a guess. Might be worth checking what webserver is in use in your hosted environment, and what version it is, compared to what's on your local machine. Or it could be a config thing. I'm speculating somewhat, as you can tell

Comment: Yes, and documentation is not very clear. For example, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status says that server errors are 500-599, but only 500-511 are given. This is exactly what I have noticed: for codes in range 500-511 it works, but for higher values it returns 200.

Comment: https://httptoolkit.tech/blog/new-http-status-code-555/ and https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-divilly-status-555-00 may be of interest.  500-599 are allocated as usable for server errors, yes, but not all of the slots are used or defined or standardised yet, thus allowing for future enhancements or changes in technology which are not yet anticipated. If you note, the MDN article says `If you receive a response that is not in this list, it is a non-standard response, possibly custom to the server's software.`, and it links you to the w3 RFCs specifying what has been standardised

Comment: So it appears that your webserver only allows you to use codes which are recognised standards

Comment: Most probably, although they claim they have no restrictions. Anyway, it's better to stick to standards. Thank you guys both for your help.

Comment: Maybe no intentional restrictions, but it could be just a config thing, or what's enabled (or not) in that version of the server software